# How to write the grave accent to add code in the comment section?

Tags: bug, comments, code-formatting

I have a magic keyboard from Apple set on US language and I try to find the keyboard shortcut for the grave accent (`) to add code in the comment section on askubuntu.com.

I don't want to copy-paste the grave accent (`) every time.

I searched on Google, tried different websites in vain.

In the comment section it's written:

```
Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`.
```

Comment: Ironically, I actually find it quicker to paste the grave than to type it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the <kbd>`</kbd> is the top left standard key (to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd>) on both US an UK keyboards.

Images from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards).

UK Keyboard:
[image]

US Keyboard:
[image]

Comment: Okay finally, it was because I have the English-Korean Apple Magic Keyboard and the ` is not displayed at the top left as you can see here: https://imgur.com/jwXMORF